# AWS Pinpoint custom attribute - the value of 'true'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I have an issue with AWS Pinpoint endpoints, custom attributes configuration and hope that someone in this forum can assist.

I am creating (using NodeJS) an endpoint in AWS with the custom attribute of "Trigger":"true" (lowercase)

but from time to time, I can see that there are some endpoint with the value "Trigger":"TRUE" (uppercase).
I didn't manage to find what the root cause of it.

Maybe AWS Pinpoint treats the string "true" as a boolean and converting it to "TRUE"?

I tried to debug my code but I am creating this endpoints with 'true' in lowercase